# What is the optimal way to store data from HTML table?

Tags: c#, html, csquery

I am currently reading in an HTML document using CsQuery. This document has several HTML tables and I need to read in the data while preserving the structure. At the moment, I simply have a List of List of List of strings. This is a list of tables containing a list of rows containing a list of cells containing the content as a string.

```
 List<List<List<string>>> page_tables = document_div.Cq().Find("TABLE")
    .Select(table => table.Cq().Find("TR")
               .Select(tr => tr.Cq().Find("td")
                               .Select(td => td.InnerHTML).ToList())
               .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Is there a better way to store this data, so I can easily access particular tables, and specific rows and cells? I'm writing several methods that deal with this page_tables object so I need to nail down its formulation first.

Comment: @JLRishe already mentioned :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to store this data, so I can easily access particular tables, and specific rows and cells?

On most occassions, well-formed HTML fits nicely into an XML structure so you could store it as an XML document. LINQ to XML would make querying *very* easy

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.parse("<html>...</html>");
var cellData = doc.Descendant("td").Select(x => x.Value);
```

Based on the comments I feel obliged to point out that there are a couple of other scenarios where this can fall over such as

- When HTML-encoded content like `&nbsp;` is used
- Valid HTML which doesn't require a closing tag e.g. `<br>` is used

(With that said, these things can be handled by some pre-processing)

To summarise, it's by all means not the most *robust* approach, however, if you can be sure that the HTML you are parsing fits the bill then it would be a pretty neat solution.

Comment: @Oscar give me a good example of where HTML won't fit nicely into an XML document? I'm sure there are some scenarios but I am struggling to think of any.

Comment: @James `<tr><td>2</td><td>b<td></tr>`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy in fairness, that's not valid/well-formed HTML. Of course, that won't prevent a browser from displaying it but my point is it would make sense in that scenario to fix the HTML (if possible).

Comment: @James that was just first example came to my mind - it's valid to have not closed tags in html

Comment: @James `<p>Hello<br><br>Hello again</p>` and  `<p>Hello&nbsp;again</p>` are two examples of perfectly valid HTML but that would cause `XDocument.Parse` to throw.

Comment: @JLRishe those are good examples actually. I guess this approach can be quite brittle, but as I have suggested on most occasions it will  probably do the job.

Comment: @James I think there are already good examples in previous comments. Just another consideration: many web pages don't even have valid html. There are tons of sites with unclosed tags, for example. I suffered this when building a web crawler.

Comment: @Oscar yep I have updated my answer to say specifically "well-formed" XML. I think for the most part it can work but there are of course scenarios where it just won't (as suggested).

Comment: Ok! So I could use XDocument instead of CsQuery entirely? Or is it possible to pass an IDomObject to XDocument? Also, in principle my table cells could well have HTML-encoded content, <br> tags and other nonsense but I can have a method that strips that out before passing it to XDocument.

Comment: @mortenalbring I have never used `CsQuery` so I couldn't comment. I presume there is a way to return the entire HTML from a CsQuery? Just looked at the [repo](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) and looks like what you would be after is something like `XDocument.Parse(csQuery.Render())`. The beauty of the XML approach as well is you could actually just render the parts that you need i.e. `XDocument.Parse(document_div.Cs().Find("TABLE").render())` - this would just put the table into the HTML structure and ignore all the other HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could go fully OOP and write some model classes:

```
// Code kept short, minimal ctors
public class Cell
{
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public Cell() { this.Content = string.Empty; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<Cell> Cells {get;set;}
    public Row() { this.Cells = new List<Cell>(); }
}

public class Table
{
    public List<Row> Rows {get;set;}
    public Table() { this.Rows = new List<Row>(); }
}
```

And then fill them up, for example like this:

```
var tables = new List<Table>();
foreach(var table in document_div.Cq().Find("TABLE"))
{
    var t = new Table();
    foreach(var tr in table.Cq().Find("TR"))
    {
        var r = new Row();
        foreach(var td in tr.Cq().Find("td"))
        {
            var c = new Cell();
            c.Contents = td.InnerHTML;
            r.Cells.Add(c);
        }
        t.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    tables.Add(t);
}

// Assuming the HTML was correct, now you have a cleanly organized 
// class structure representing the tables!

var aTable = tables.First();
var firstRow = aTable.Rows.First();
var firstCell = firstRow.Cells.First();
var firstCellContents = firstCell.Contents;
...
```

I'd probably choose this approach because I always prefer to know exactly what my data looks like, especially if/when I'm parsing from external/unsafe/unreliable sources.

Comment: This is great! I'm totally going to use this, even if I also implement XDocument as suggested in a different answer. Thank you!

Comment: I do get an error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}, when trying the line r.Cells.Add(c);
This confuses me, because a new instance has been created by var c = new Cell(); surely?

Comment: That's correct, but my sample didn't include any initialization so probably some `new`s must be added for the Lists

Comment: I fixed it by declaring a new list first and then associating it with the object afterwards.

Comment: I took the opportunity to amend the samples, I added ctors to allow simpler reusage of code

Comment: Ah! That makes perfect sense! Thank you. This community is incredible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to store this data, so I can easily access
>   particular tables, and specific rows and cells?

If you want to easily access table data, then create class which will hold data from table row with nicely named properties for corresponding columns. E.g. if you have users table

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Bob</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Joe</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would create following class to hold row data:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Second step would be parsing users from HTML. I suggest to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) for parsing HTML:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();            
doc.Load("index.html");
var users = from r in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr")
            let cells = r.SelectNodes("td")
            select new User
            {
                Id = Int32.Parse(cells[0].InnerText),
                Name = cells[1].InnerText
            };
// NOTE: you can check cells count before accessing them by index
```

Now you have collection of strongly-typed user objects (you can save them to list, to array or to dictionary - it depends on how you are going to use them). E.g.

```
 var usersDictionary = users.ToDictionary(u => u.Id);
 // Getting user by id
 var user = usersDictionary[2];
 // now you can read user.Name
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work. There's a variable number of tables, each with an variable number of columns and rows, and it's not known precisely which cells correspond to what data types. That's why I just want to store and preserve the table structure, and then do stuff with it afterwards.

Comment: @mortenalbring OK then what you are going to do with data from table with unknown columns and data types? E.g. you have list of values `"45", "Tuesday", "false", "true", ""` - is there any practical use of them? Data on its own is pretty useless - you should know meaning of data

Comment: There's several different sorts of table the script could encounter, I need to run some tests against certain criteria before I can assign the datatypes to the table structure. That's why I want to store the table in the most general way and preserve structure.

Comment: @mortenalbring then use `var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");` - you will have html node with all table data. (I still don't understand why you want to have unknown data)

Comment: Does that have any advantages over my current method of just List<List<List<string>>>?

Comment: @mortenalbring data of type `List<List<List<string>>>` is already disadvantage. Table node retrieved in one simple line and it has set of HTML specific methods to get or manipulate node data

Answer (score 0):

Since your parsing an HTML table. Could you use an ADO.Net DataTable? If the content doesn't have too many row or col spans this may be an option, you wouldn't have to roll your own and it could be easily saved to a database or list of entities or whatever. Plus you get the benefit of strongly typed data types. As long as the HTML tables are consistent I would prefer an approach like this to make interoperability with the rest of the framework seamless and a ton less work.